# I have the "illegal start of expression" error

Tags: java

What i want to do basically is to set a pointer of an object which is inside an array to point to an element of an array which is an array of objects.Thanks in advance.Please i need your help.

```
System.out.println( k + " alkanes will be constructed");
    calka = new c1[k];
    h1alka = new h1[k];
    h2alka = new h2[k];
    h3alka = new h3[k];
    h4alka = new h4[k];
    for(i=0;i<k;i++){
        calka[i].set_p1(&h1alka[i]);
        calka[i].set_p2(&h2alka[i]);
        calka[i].set_p3(&h3alka[i]);
        calka[i].set_p4(&h4alka[i]);
        h1alka[i].set_p(&calka[i]);
        h2alka[i].set_p(&calka[i]);
        h3alka[i].set_p(&calka[i]);
        h4alka[i].set_p(&calka[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you putting an ampersand in before your array names?

Comment: Java is not C and doesn't support *pointers*. What you're trying to do, i.e. obtain a pointer to an array element, is impossible in Java. If the array is an array of objects, you can get the reference *value* from the array element, but you cannot get a pointer to the reference itself (pointer to pointer).

Comment: @Andreas... and that should probably come as an answer. Most likely good job guessing the OP's context.

Answer (score 0):

Java is not C and doesn't support pointers.

What you're trying to do, i.e. obtain a pointer to an array element, is impossible in Java.

If the array is an array of objects, you can get the reference value from the array element, but you cannot get a pointer to the reference itself (pointer to pointer).

Comment: Yes, but if i write calka[i].set_p1(h1alka) the match(calka[i] point to h1alka[i]) that i want will not exist.So what can i write?Thanks in advance

Comment: You should start by thoroughly reevaluating what you're doing and why you need pointer-to-pointer logic. Without knowing why you need it, it's difficult to advise on how to do what you want. See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Ok, thanks man but i still dont know why we dont speak greek :).